# Playhaven SDK Not Working

Tags: ios

I integrated Playhaven Full Screen ad in my App. there are two action performing while full screen ad Load. One is Dismiss the view and Second Go to the App Store. I have to check Which Functions are called when both actions are Performed.

I already Tried below Function

```
-(void)request:(PHPublisherContentRequest *)request contentDidDismissWithType:(PHPublisherContentDismissType *)type{

    NSLog(@"Type %@",type);

}
```

but it Return me the String PHPublisherContentUnitTriggeredDismiss in both case.

How to add Diffrent action on Both Button Clicked ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the Playhaven SDK doesn't differentiate between the type of dismissal in triggering the the contentDidDismissWithType delegate. I know that this is something we are looking into adding in the future, however.