# can't display playhaven Full screen ad in my iPhone application

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, playhaven

I have an iPhone application in which I integrated the **revmob** SDK and **chartboost** SDK successfully but **playhaven** SDK doesn't work.

I have downloaded it's complete SDK also referred to [here on this old Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14133809/1458943) . I still don't see the ad in my application. Is there any good tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

My PlayHavan Working sample: https://app.box.com/s/lc2p8jhngn5o8hxeuw3y

Code:

```
#define PLAYHAVAN_TOKEN @"e1aa8bfe19d74ba3a30d9caa7f69a083"
#define PLAYHAVAN_SECRET @"e915e3ca790546b88ab252d032876b6a"  

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   [self initPlayHavan];
   [self showPlayHavanFullScreenAds];
}


-(void) initPlayHavan
{
    [[PHPublisherContentRequest requestForApp: PLAYHAVAN_TOKEN secret: PLAYHAVAN_SECRET placement:@"game_launch" delegate:self] preload]; //level_complete

    _notificationView = [[PHNotificationView alloc] initWithApp:PLAYHAVAN_TOKEN secret:PLAYHAVAN_SECRET placement:@"game_launch"];
    _notificationView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
}


-(void)showPlayHavanFullScreenAds
{
  PHPublisherContentRequest *request = [PHPublisherContentRequest requestForApp: PLAYHAVAN_TOKEN secret: PLAYHAVAN_SECRET placement:@"game_launch" delegate:self];
    [request send];
}
```

Make sure you added placement `game_launch` and assigned interstitial ads for this placement.